# sklearn - predict top 3-4 labels in multi-label classifications from text documents

Tags: python, scikit-learn, classification, text-classification, multilabel-classification

I currently have a classifier `MultinomialNB()` set up using `CountVectorizer` for feature extraction from text documents, and whilst this works quite well, I want to use the same methodology to predict the top 3-4 labels, not just the top one.

The main reason is that there are c.90 labels and data input isn't great, resulting in a 35% accuracy for the top estimate. If I can offer the user the top 3-4 most likely labels as a suggestion, then I could significantly increase the accuracy coverage.

Any suggestions? Any pointers would be appreciated!

The current code looks like:

```
import numpy
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.cross_validation import KFold
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix, accuracy_score

df = pd.read_csv("data/corpus.csv", sep=",", encoding="latin-1")

df = df.set_index('id')
df.columns = ['class', 'text']

data = df.reindex(numpy.random.permutation(df.index))

pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('count_vectorizer',   CountVectorizer(ngram_range=(1, 2))),
    ('classifier',         MultinomialNB())
])

k_fold = KFold(n=len(data), n_folds=6, shuffle=True)

for train_indices, test_indices in k_fold:
    train_text = data.iloc[train_indices]['text'].values
    train_y = data.iloc[train_indices]['class'].values.astype(str)

    test_text = data.iloc[test_indices]['text'].values
    test_y = data.iloc[test_indices]['class'].values.astype(str)

    pipeline.fit(train_text, train_y)
    predictions = pipeline.predict(test_text)
    confusion = confusion_matrix(test_y, predictions)

    accuracy = accuracy_score(test_y, predictions)
    print accuracy
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have done your predictions, you can get the probability of each labels with:

```
labels_probability = pipeline.predict_proba(test_text)
```

You will get the probability for each label. see http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html#sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.predict_proba

Answer (score 1):

To grab the top N labels just do :

```
import numpy as np

n = 3
top_n_predictions = np.argsort(probas, axis=1)[:, -n:]
```